# Can't assign the value of the_field() to a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress. I have a file path in a field (say "submenu/abc.php" in field "ACFfield"). I want to include that info on a webpage.

If I do:

```
<?php include "submenu/abc.php" ?>
```

This works fine. But I need to do something like:

```
<?php 

    $file = the_field(ACFfield);
    include($file);

?>
```

This, however just prints out "submenu/abc.php", from the first line (which I wouldn't want visible anyway).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[`the_field(ACFfield);`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) doesn't return anything. It just prints the filename out. Use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead, which will return the value.

Comment: Which is why I shouldn't code without sleep! I'd say thanks, but I see you don't like that!